# What does 'fandom community with a veracious output of fanfiction' mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

Could you please help me understand what does this part (bold type) of the sentence mean? Would you please make this sentence more clear? And do I correctly understand the word 'inspired' in this case as a 'created'?

> The book and film franchise of Harry Potter has inspired a monumental
>   **fandom community with a veracious output of fanfiction** and general
>   musings on the text and the vivid universe contained therein.

Comment: Can you please show us that you have made some effort at understanding this? It's: ***voracious***, by the way. You might want to look up that word to get started. Your question does not inspire me to give you an answer, yet.

Comment: **voracious** is a synonym for "ravenous", but I guess it's becoming a synonym for "huge" by those who don't know that "voracity" involves the ability to *consume* (not produce) huge amounts.

Comment: To echo Lambie's comment, please show what steps you have taken to understand the phrase. Have you looked up the definitions of the individual words? Do you think you understand them individually, but not together?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Yes, it is rather odd to use the word in this context, particularly when followed immediately by "output". I suppose it is simply used as an intensifier, but "doubleplus" would have been better.

Comment: "monumental" is also a word that grates on my nerves there :)

Comment: *Ron barfed up a voracious amount of food.*

Comment: Thanks guys, thanks all of you. I'm really dumb and stupid. I read that text a million times and didn't think about 'voracious'. Sorry for English, I'm a non-native speaker.

Comment: By the way, "inspired" doesn't exactly mean "created", but it is closely related.  The fans created their own community, and the franchises were the reason or the model for creating it.  It's more like "Hey, look at those books and films.  That's given me an idea...."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't make any sense as the words stand (though it is pretty clear what it meant).

I think it is a [malapropism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malapropism) at two levels. First, I think somebody has confused *veracious* ["habitually speaking the truth", or "characterized by truthfulness"](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/veracious) with *voracious* ["exceedingly eager or avid"](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/voracious). Secondly, I think that they don't realise that the primary meaning of *voracious* is "craving or consuming large quantities of food": as far as I know, this gets extended to eager to consume or experience, but not to creating things.

Answer (score 0):

The preposition **with** there means "having" or "characterized by".